# Google Analytics Picks Up Traffic from Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Tag Manager to add Analytics tracker to my wordpress site https://mile.app and only that. But somehow, Analytics picks up traffic from subdomain like task.mile.app.

I'm pretty sure I only add my tracker to the https://mile.app. Would you please help me with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, you can just use GTM to filter out all data that has task in hostname.

or use GTM to make a blocking trigger that would fire on task hostname.

or find out where exactly GTM is being loaded on task and try to fix it from the site side.

Three completely different approaches to the problem and each will work.

Comment: The problem is the tag isn’t fired at all on the Task subdomain because I didn’t install the container there. But I will try your solutions anyway. Thanks!